# Can a page_id and a post_id be same?

Tags: posts, pages, id

Wordpress generates ID's for each page/post. Do pages in wordpress share the same ID column in the database as the posts? I mean, if a site has both posts and pages, can one or more page_ID's be same as some Post_ID's?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, all posts, pages and other custom post types exist in the same table (`wp_posts`) and they all share the same ID column. The ID is unique to each entry regardless of its post type.